# Взаимодействие с USB устройством без API

Tags: c#, c

Имеется usbлоггер/мультиметр, к нему есть драйвера, есть оригинальное ПО, но нет ни документации, ни API (производитель не поставляет). Стоит задача: написать ПО для взаимодействия с данным устройством (оригинальное ПО по неизвестным мне причинам не устраивает руководство). Как можно выцыганить,отковырять, слизать методы обмена с данным устройством? Реально ли это вообще? Язык предпочтительно C#, но можно и чистый Си (знания можно восполнить).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На английском языке этой теме (реверс-инженерии) посвящен целый сайт Stack Exchange. Конкретно реверс-инжиниринг устройства через USB обсуждается, например, тут: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/how-to-reverse-engineer-simple-usb-device-windows-linux

Вкратце: используйте VMWare + Virtual USB analyzer, чтобы поймать и визуализировать трафик между USB-устройством и системой (виртуальной машиной).

[image: скриншот]

- [Сайт](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/)
- [Туториал](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html)

Как альтернатива - [еще вот такой тул](http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/post/2011/04/06/Sniffing-USB-traffic-with-VMWare).

Answer (score 4):

Для начала, стоит восстановить протокол при помощи USB-анализатора. Например, [MMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn741264(v=vs.85).aspx) (но наверняка должны быть и другие). Тут все зависит от сложности протокола: простой протокол можно восстановить быстро, сложный протокол восстановить практически невозможно.

Также в деле восстановления протокола может помочь дизасемблирование драйвера.

Когда протокол восстановлен - можно использовать драйвер [WinUSB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196(v=vs.85).aspx) для общения с устройством.